# Injecting CSS or JS into Chrome on Android

Tags: javascript, android, css, google-chrome, plugins

Is there a way to inject (non-malicious) JavaScript (or CSS) statements into Chrome on Android whenever a matching URL is loaded?

Basically, I'd like to modify how some sites look.

One example would be `m.facebook.com`:
I'd like to inject something like:

```
#header: {position:fixed; margin-top:-2px}
#root:{margin-top:40px}
```

Unfortunately, Google doesn't extend the plugins API for the mobile platform!

Any thoughts?

Comment: There's no straightforward way since [plug-ins are not supported on mobile](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/2710225?hl=en). A few ideas: use a proxy that you own and edit the traffic on the fly not recommended security wise. [Build your own browser from source and edit as you wish](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27059494/source-code-of-google-chrome-android-app) which is a hassle to do.

Comment: @HamZa, routing traffic through a proxy is not an option in my case, unfortunately, but I like the idea. Thanks!

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/a/21612566/32453 for injecting

Answer (score 2):

See how to [create a bookmarklet](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/159308/how-can-a-bookmarklet-be-added-on-mobile-chrome-without-copying-and-pasting/210701#210701), create one and put your JS code to it.

Example of the code:

```
javascript:(function(e){e.setAttribute("src","JS-URL-to-inject");document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(e);})(document.createElement("script"));void(0);
```

To execute the bookmarklet, follow instructions in the above link [1](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/159308/how-can-a-bookmarklet-be-added-on-mobile-chrome-without-copying-and-pasting/210701#210701).